# Consulta de Distinct con INNER JOIN en SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenos dias:
Tengo dos tablas en la cual las uno por medio la referencia, y hace bien la consulta, pero quiero que se pongan los demás campos de mi tabla **entsal** y que sean igual a la referencia, por ejemplo agregar nombreS,tea de la table entsal.

Ejemplo de mi consulta:

```
select * from (SELECT DISTINCT referencia from salidas) entsal INNER JOIN (SELECT referencia FROM salidas) salidas ON entsal.referencia= salidas.referencia
```

table entsal
campos=nombreS(char),referencia(char),tea(numeric)

table salidas
campos=vin(char),estado(char),referencia(char)

Quiero que no me repita las referencias y ademas me traiga los datos correspodientes a mi table de entsal con su referencia que tiene.
Alguien me podria ayudar con mi duda, por favor.

Comment: porque un distinct en entsal? si referencia es la llave primaria de salidas el distinct no es necesario.

Comment: no quiero que se repitan las referencias por eso el distinct y funciona bien la consulta me trae las referencias de ambas tablas sin repetirlas, pero quiero que las de la table entsal me aparezcan los demas campos de mi table que sea igual a su referencia

Comment: ¿cuál es la estructura de las tablas involucradas en la consulta?

Comment: osea como agrega nombreS y tea de mi table entsal(campos char) pero que me respite en distinct ?

Comment: Alguien podria ayudarme con mi duda, gracias.

Comment: puedes publicar el DDL de las tablas?

Comment: Sugiero que añadas un ejemplo de los datos de entrada y un ejemplo de la salida de la consulta que quieres realizar.

Comment: requieres ayuda pero no quieres poner mas información para que te puedan ayudar? si no agregas tus tablas difícilmente se podrá visualizar que es lo que quieres hacer.

Answer (score 2):

Deberias ponerle un alias a cada tabla y seleccionar anteponiendo el alias, por ejemplo:

```
Select Distinct A.Campo1,A.Campo2,B.Campo1,B.Campo2 from tabla1 as A 
INNER JOIN Tabla2 as B 
ON A.referencia= B.referencia
```

Answer (score 1):

Voy a partir haciendo las siguientes suposiciones:

1. La consulta de ejemplo está mal formada ya que de hecho se está nombrando como entsal y salidas a la misma consulta:

   SELECT referencia FROM salidas
2. Para que una columna sea usada como referencia en una llave foránea, esta columna debe contar como mínimo con la restricción unique, por ende el uso del distinct lo encuentro redundante.
3. El inner join se puede hacer entre ambas tablas directamente simplemente ejecutando:

   `select * from entsal inner join salidas ON entsal.referencia = salidas.referencia;`
4. Si la llave foránea no está definida, hay que tener en cuenta que pueden llegar a existir mas de una fila con un mismo valor para referencia en cualquiera de las tablas,  por lo que el join retornaría mas filas de las que se pueden esperar, para  ejemplificar ese comportamiento, se pueden des-documentar los insert en el ejemplo que dejó.

[Ejemplo en ideone](https://ideone.com/cunPsf)

Comment: si tu consulta esta bien, pero falta el distinct porque en ambas tablas se repite la referencia

Comment: ya te entendi, uppp jajajajajajajjaa, perdon si ya me funciona, perdona y gracias por tu tiempo :) excelente tarde Dios te bendiga

Comment: @AraceLiTorres, si esta respuesta solucionó tu inquietud, por favor marca la pregunta como (respuesta aceptada).